# Start debug at any point

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

Is it possible to enter debug mode at any point without setting a break point since the location of the code is unknown to me?

The code I'm looking at was written by a genius in a hurry and as such, I'm struggling - the code (and project) is vast and I'd rather not step through the entire thing especially since events are being trigged on new threads, others are polling on other threads, API's are being executed etc and as such debugging is difficult.

When the application is running, code is being executed at any point. So, is there a way to tell Visual Studio (2010 or 2012) "add a break point to where ever you currently are (or if you're in an API or something unmanaged, wait until you're back in the solution)?". At least I can then get an idea what project/files are being executed and start debugging from that point. Or is there already an 'approach' for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try press the little 'pause' button while running in VS, that should 'break' it.

Comment: I've been using VS since 2005, and I never used the pause button... I feel some what daft! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging, there is a "pause" icon on the toolbar that will break execution wherever it is.